# How can I calculate the probability of two independent events with only the union and the intersection?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose two events A and B are two independent events with $P(A) > P(B)$ and $P(A ∪ B) = 0.626$ and $P(A ∩ B) = 0.144$, determine the values of P(A) and P(B).

So far I have:

$$P(A ∩ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A U B)$$
$$0.144 = P(A) + P(B) - 0.626$$

Comment: You haven't used the independence of $A$ and $B$, which will give you another equation so you can solve $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For independent events you have
$$ P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) \\
P(A\cup B) + P(A\cap B)  = P(A) + P(B) $$
If you know the product and sum of two numbers, finding the numbers themselves is a matter of solving a quadratic equation (and in fact one of the classical formulation of quadratic problems).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $$P(A) = p\implies P(B) = {P(A\cap B)\over P(A)} = {0,144\over p}$$ then by PIE we have $$ 0.626 = p+{0,144\over p}-0,144$$

Now solve for $p$...